# Awk is overwriting letters when printing reversed order, why?

Tags: bash, awk

I'm currently using awk to replicate the function `uniq -c` with commas as delimiters.

This gives correct output:

```
$ cut --delimiter=, -s -f2 wordlist.csv | awk '{ cnts[$0] += 1 } END { for (v in cnts) print cnts[v], v}' OFS="," | head

2,laecherlichen
111,doctrine
1,cremonas
1,embedding
1,conincks
2,similiter
1,mitgesellen
1,hysnelement
1,geringem
1,aquarian
```

However, if I reverse the awk command `print cnts[v], v` into `print v, cnts[v]`, I get a messed up output:

```
$ cut --delimiter=, -s -f2 wordlist.csv | awk '{ cnts[$0] += 1 } END { for (v in cnts) print v, cnts[v]}' OFS="," | head

,2echerlichen
,111rine
,1emonas
,1bedding
,1nincks
,2militer
,1tgesellen
,1snelement
,1ringem
,1uarian
```

I'm confused by this output, because I'm expecting something like `word,1` as output. What is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Most likely you have DOS line feed characters i.e. `\r` before end of line `\n`. You can use `RS` variable in `awk` to ignore this:

```
cut --delimiter=, -s -f2 wordlist.csv | awk -v RS='\r|\n' '{
    cnts[$0] += 1 } END { for (v in cnts) print cnts[v], v}' OFS="," | head
```

However if you show your csv file I believe even `cut` and `head` can be removed from above commands.

PS: Thanks to @Bammar you can also run:

```
dos2unix file.csv
```

to convert your csv file to unix compatible file.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar: I keep forgetting about `dos2unix` since I don't have it on my OSX.